# テキストファイルの末尾からｎ行を読み込むには

Tags: java, テキストファイル, file-io

テキストファイルの末尾から指定した行数のテキストを効率的に取り出したいです。
Linux の tail コマンドのようなものです。

```
File file = new File("c:¥¥tmp¥¥test.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

String str;
while((str = br.readLine()) != null){
  ・・・
}

br.close();
```

このようなファイルの先頭から順番に１行ずつ取得する方法を応用して最後のｎ行を取り出すことは出来るのですが、この方法だとファイルサイズが大きい時に処理時間が長くなってしまいます。
ファイルの末尾から１行ずつ取り出す方法はあるでしょうか？

対象のテキストファイルは以下の想定です。

- 文字コードは UTF-8
- 改行はCRLF、LFが混在
- １行の文字数に上限なし

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Apache Commons-IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) ライブラリの [`org.apache.commons.io.input`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/input/package-summary.html) パッケージに参考になりそうなものがありました。

- [`ReversedLinesFileReader`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/input/ReversedLinesFileReader.html): テキストファイルを末尾から読むクラス
- [`Tailer`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/input/Tailer.html) : tail のようにファイル監視機能付の末尾出力の仕組み

仕様は、[`FileReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) に似ているので、使い方が直観的です。

ReadFromTail.java:

```java
import org.apache.commons.io.input.ReversedLinesFileReader;
import java.io.*;

public class ReadFromTail {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try (ReversedLinesFileReader r = new ReversedLinesFileReader( new File(args[0]))) {
        System.out.println(r.readLine());
    }
  }
}
```

```
$ javac -cp commons-io-2.4.jar ReadFromTail.java
$ java -cp commons-io-2.4.jar ReadFromTail c:¥tmp¥test.txt
I'm the Last Line!!!
```

`ReversedLinesFileReader` のソースを見ると、デフォルト 4kb でファイル全体をブロックに分割されているとしてから、末尾ブロックから読みだしていました。 読みだし位置の指定は、 [`RandomAccessFile.seek()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#seek-long-) です。他に、UTF-8 や Shift-JIS エンコーディングに対応する部分が興味を引く感じ。

ReversedLinesFileReader.java (抜粋):

```java
...

randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
totalByteLength = randomAccessFile.length();
int lastBlockLength = (int) (totalByteLength % blockSize);
if (lastBlockLength > 0) {
    totalBlockCount = totalByteLength / blockSize + 1;
} else {
    totalBlockCount = totalByteLength / blockSize;
    if (totalByteLength > 0) {
        lastBlockLength = blockSize;
    }
}
currentFilePart = new FilePart(totalBlockCount, lastBlockLength, null);

...

int dataLength = length + (leftOverOfLastFilePart != null ? leftOverOfLastFilePart.length : 0);
this.data = new byte[dataLength];
final long off = (no - 1) * blockSize;

// read data
if (no > 0 /* file not empty */) {
    randomAccessFile.seek(off);
    final int countRead = randomAccessFile.read(data, 0, length);

...
```

Comment: `ReversedLinesFileReader`いいですね。文字コードの指定もできて素晴らしいです。使わせて頂きます。

Answer (score 4):

ファイルをシーケンシャルに読んでいくのではなく、ランダムアクセスする必要があります。
`SeekableByteChannel(Java7)`を使用し、ファイル位置を指定しながら必要なデータを末尾から取得します。

```
// 読み込みモード
Path path = Paths.get("./", "test.dat");
SeekableByteChannel channel = Files.newByteChannel(path, StandardOpenOption.READ);
// ファイルサイズ取得
long fileSize = channnel.size();

// 取得のためのバッファを用意
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);

// 末尾(fileSize-1)から1024byteを取得
channel.position(fileSize - 1 - 1024);
channel.read(buffer);
```

あとはアクセスしている位置を保持し、繰り返し取得しながら改行コード(データを逆から辿るならば`CRLF`と`LF`が混在していたとしても`LF='\n'`の個数のみをカウントすれば良い)を見つけて必要な行数分データを取っていくロジックにすれば良いです(このロジックの場合、ファイルサイズが1024byteより小さい場合の考慮が必要となります)。

取得したバイトデータを指定された文字コードで変換するには以下のようにします。

```
new String(buffer.array(), "UTF-8");
```

この変換処理は欲しいデータ分たまったあと一気にすれば良いです(指定行数分の取得ロジック部では改行コードのバイトデータをチェックしていれば良い)。

Answer (score 2):

RandomAccessFileを使って末尾から読んでいく方法はどうでしょうか？
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/7/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html

// コードは後ほど時間がとれたら追加します

Answer (score 1):

Java8ならFiles.linesが良いかと思います。
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-

それ以前ならjava.io.LineNumberReaderクラスを使うのはどうでしょう。
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html

Comment: どちらもシーケンシャルアクセスなのでファイルサイズが大きい場合、速度が遅くなりませんか？

Comment: >...この方法だとファイルサイズが大きい時に処理時間が長くなってしまいます。
わたしのこちらの回答時の前提としては、Javaバイトコードのステップ数が減る方法を優先して考えていました。
ライブラリ側処理で性能を担保する想定です。

(話題が逸れる部分がありますが)
この文脈での「ファイルサイズが大きい」と「処理時間が長く」とはどれぐらいのオーダーを想定したものでしょうか。
例えば、ファイルサイズとして、1行が1000文字以上、もしくは行数が1万行以上、などです。

ほかにも、想定するJavaVMの実行環境の違いはどうでしょうか。
PCやサーバ上でしょうか、Androidスマートフォン上での実行でしょうか。
サーバ上を考えるなら、('15現在だと)ファイルアクセスは、ストレージの物理層ですとSSDやネットワークディスクがもつバッファで数MBの入力はまとめて処理されますし、
メモリ上でも、OSでのIOバッファによるブロック読み込みも結果に影響するでしょう。
初めてファイルを読み込む場合と、ディスクキャッシュによりメモリ上に読み混み済みの場合で結果が大きく変化するでしょう。
スマートフォンでは潤沢なハードウェア性能を前提にできないため、固定メモリバッファ管理などの方法を検討するでしょう

あわせて、Java側から呼ばれるライブラリが使うJNIのパフォーマンス計測と比較するでしょう。

Comment: ええと、何やら難しく考えておられるようですが、質問者さんは「シーケンシャルなアクセスでは大きいファイルの場合遅くなった(私の実行環境では)」とおっしゃっているわけで･･･ 
別のシーケンシャルなアクセス方法を提示されても解決しないのではないでしょうか。。 
(もちろん逆方向からのシーケンシャルアクセスができればそれに越したことはありません)